# Не получается подключить библиотеки в Maven IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven

[image: Не получается подключить библиотеки в Maven IntelliJ IDEA]
Народ, всем привет! Такая вот проблема никак уже целый день не могу решить. У меня  не получается подключить стороние библиотеки в Maven IntelliJ IDEA. При том любую. Пишет всё как представлено на скриншоте. Нажимаю реимпорт. Не помогает.
Или вот например пишут в pox.xml:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
            <version>9.4.0.M1</version>
</dependency>
```

IDE мне также версию 9.4.0.M1 выделяет красным и пишет dependency not found. И так буквально со всем...

Comment: Локальный репозиторий Maven находится не на сетевом диске?

Comment: Проблему решили на английской версии сайта. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39890619/i-cant-work-with-mavens-dependency-in-intellij-idea/39891655#39891655

Answer (score 1, accepted):

проверьте в настройках idea подключение к сети, возможно maven не может подключиться к удаленному репозиторию. Проверьте настройки прокси в file ->settings -> apperearance -> system setting -> HTTP proxy